# How can I generate a sorted list of LogN unique numbers, where N is the given size of the array?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

So basically I want to generate random numbers and put them into a list with a given size of N.

for example, this generates a sorted list where the number of unique numbers is equal to roughly N/2
How can I modify this to make the unique numbers roughly equal to LogN?

```
     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         list.add(i, list.get(i) + new Java.util.Random.nextInt(2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a consistently accurate list of `log(n)` unique numbers, why not generate them first? You can fill an array later.

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class RandomExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(fillLogNUnique(100, 0, 100));
 }


 public static List <Integer> fillLogNUnique(final int n, final int lowLimit, final int highLimit) {
  final Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

  // Assuming log base 2.0.

  final int requiredUniqueCount = (int) Math.floor(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2.0));
  final List <Integer> uniques = random
        .ints(lowLimit, highLimit)
        .limit(requiredUniqueCount)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

  return IntStream
        .range(0, n)
        .map(x -> uniques.get(random.nextInt(uniques.size())))
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
}
```

The inputs are `n`: number of required random numbers, `lowLimit`: the lower bounds for the generated numbers, and `highLimit`: the upper bound.

The output for that is:

```
[17, 29, 98, 17, 17, 29, 64, 64, 64, 17, 98, 98, 91, 17, 64, 50, 17, 50, 50, 64, 98, 91, 29, 50, 91, 50, 91, 98, 91, 98, 98, 29, 91, 91, 98, 64, 29, 98, 91, 50, 64, 50, 64, 17, 17, 50, 29, 29, 50, 50, 91, 50, 17, 17, 98, 64, 17, 98, 64, 17, 50, 17, 50, 50, 91, 50, 64, 91, 64, 91, 64, 64, 64, 91, 64, 64, 50, 50, 91, 50, 17, 17, 64, 98, 91, 17, 17, 17, 64, 50, 91, 29, 29, 91, 29, 50, 29, 91, 17, 91]
```

...which has exactly 6, as `log(100)` with base 2 has an integer value (floored) of 6.

Note that this answer is for Java >= 8.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is definitely very helpful. As for why I wanted to fill an array right away and it be sorted, well that was part of the requirement of an assignment, which I should have specified. But, it is already turned in, so thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help!